React-Vite mostrando 404 en build local pero funciona perfecto en dev
Llevo todo el dia intentado desplegar mi app con vite y react para conectarla a mi backend pero tanto en gh-pages o netlify, e incluso de forma local pasa lo mismo, en dev todo funciona de maravilla pero cuando hago "npm run build" y se genera el dist dentro de el el html solo contiene una imagen con el fondo de mi pagina y un 404, estoy usando tambien "react-router-dom"
así sale en dev:
pero en la build sea local o remota solo aparece:


Hola Juan, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu cógido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y lo agregues en formato texto (solo la parte pertinente), así evitarás el cierre de misma y recibir votos negativos.
